# Find source_location of a method when you have the Class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am looking into catching every method that is defined on a base class, looking up what file it is defined in, and then doing some logic based on that.

I currently have:

```
  # Defined in some file
  class Subclass < Base
    def foo
    end
  end


  class Base
    self.method_added(method)
      # self is a given subclass (Subclass)

      # This doesn't work. :(
      self.method(method).source_location
    end
  end
```

What I'd like to be able to do is find out the source location of that method.

I could do something like:

```
self.new.method(source).source_location
```

But don't think I should be having to instantiate anything to get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use method [Module#instance_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) to get instance method of your class:

```
instance_method(method).source_location  # `self` is unnecessary, it is added implicitly
# => ["/home/alex/Projects/test/test.rb", 23]
```

> **instance_method(symbol)** → unbound_method
>
> Returns an UnboundMethod representing the given instance method in mod.

Comment: Is there a way to just be displayed rather than providing its location?